# Us verse We for relationships

Tags: word-choice

What is more intimate when referring to two people and what is the less. I'm trying to describe the change from casual friendship to a romantic relationship.

"When we changed from we to us" or something like that

Comment: What about "change from _me_ to us"? We and us are different forms of the same word...

Answer (score 2):

"You and me" or "You and I" refer to the two of you as separate entities, while "us" or "we" refer to the two of you as a single unit.

"You and I should visit Topeka" is different from "We should visit Topeka."

"That deal will be good for you and me" is different from "That deal will be good for us."

Comment: Do you have some support for this claim?  Because I think separate/unit distinction is based on the context, not the syntax.  Do you think there's a difference between *You and I should exchange rings* and *We should exchange rings*?  How about *You and I should get tattoos* and "We should get tattoos*?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're talking about yourself and your romantic interest, the first person plural is appropriate, so both "we" and "us" depending on the grammar. E.G. "We went to a concert Friday" or "Come have dinner with us".

That said, there are certain usages where "us" takes on special meaning, as in "Let's talk about us". I.e. let's talk about our relationship.

Beyond that, I'm not sure there's a valid, pronoun-related answer to your question in English.